# Implementing Single Partition Assigner on Kafkajs

Tags: typescript, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am trying to assign a consumer on single partition of a topic using kafkajs client library in TypeScript. I am using [partitionAssigners](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming) in the consumer group as provided in documentation. I have created my SinglePartitionAssigner but it doesn't seem working.

```
import {Kafka, PartitionAssigner, EachMessagePayload, AssignerProtocol, KafkaMessage} from 'kafkajs'
import {Buffer} from 'buffer'

const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'my-app',
    brokers: ['localhost:9092']
})
const topics = ['testTopic'];
export const SinglePartitionAssigner: PartitionAssigner = () => ({
    name: 'SinglePartitionAssigner',
    version: 1,
    async assign() {
        return [
            {
                memberId: 'what',
                memberAssignment: AssignerProtocol.MemberAssignment.encode({
                    version: this.version,
                    assignment: {
                        'testTopic': [0]
                    },
                    userData: Buffer.from([]) // no idea what this is for
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    protocol({topics}) {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            metadata: AssignerProtocol.MemberMetadata.encode({
                version: this.version,
                topics,
                userData: Buffer.from([]) // no idea what this is for
            }),
        }
    }
});

const consumer = kafka.consumer({groupId: 'ashutosh', partitionAssigners: [SinglePartitionAssigner]})

// Use the partitionAssigner when you subscribe to a topic
// @ts-ignore
async function sendEvent(message: any) {
    console.log({
        key: message.key.toString(),
        value: message.value.toString(),
        headers: message.headers,
    });
}

// @ts-ignore
async function  main() {
    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({
        topic: 'testTopic',
        fromBeginning: true
    })
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({message}) => await sendEvent(message),
    });
}


main().catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

Although I am getting following output -
[image]

Events are not received, Can any one help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- In your `SinglePartitionAssigner` function, you need to use the `async` keyword before the assign function, since it returns a Promise.
- In the assign function, you should use this instead of `SinglePartitionAssigner` to refer to the current object.
- You should use the protocol function to return metadata for the assigned partitions, not the assign function.

Making changes:

```js
import { Kafka, PartitionAssigner, AssignerProtocol } from 'kafkajs'
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['localhost:9092']
})

const topics = ['testTopic']

export const SinglePartitionAssigner: PartitionAssigner = {
  name: 'SinglePartitionAssigner',
  version: 1,
  async assign({ members, topics }) {
    return members.map((member) => ({
      memberId: member.memberId,
      memberAssignment: AssignerProtocol.MemberAssignment.encode({
        version: this.version,
        assignment: {
          [topics[0]]: [0] // Assign partition 0 of the only topic to this consumer
        },
        userData: Buffer.alloc(0)
      })
    }))
  },
  protocol({ topics }) {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      metadata: AssignerProtocol.MemberMetadata.encode({
        version: this.version,
        topics,
        userData: Buffer.alloc(0)
      })
    }
  }
}

const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'ashutosh', partitionAssigners: [SinglePartitionAssigner] })

async function sendEvent(message: any) {
  console.log({
    key: message.key.toString(),
    value: message.value.toString(),
    headers: message.headers,
  })
}

async function main() {
  await consumer.connect()
  await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'testTopic', fromBeginning: true })
  await consumer.run({ eachMessage: async ({ message }) => await sendEvent(message) })
}

main().catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Comment: it's not compiling, Albeit it seems there is limitation in lib. I have solved my usecase using node-rdkafka

Comment: What error are you getting?